# Storing URL frontier and distributing work for web crawler?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, web-crawler, message-queue

I want to make a cost efficient distributed crawler (i.e. I can add extra servers to it to process URLs faster) that is focused on crawling entire individual sites as a service. It would crawl every URL of a target site as well as download e.g. any images or files the site directly referenced on other sites (but not crawl other sites beyond this). As target site owners would give permission to have their sites crawled, the crawler could be less polite e.g. download 20 pages per second.

Does this architecture sound sensible?

- AWS ECS2 instances as workers that can be killed or brought online as needed.
- AWS RDS database running PostgreSQL to store page metadata.
- The URL frontier (URLs to be crawled), list of seen URLs, URL crawl depth etc. would be stored in the database.
- Workers would poll the database for new work and which worker is working on what is stored on the database as well.
- I'd maintain a database table of URLs to be looked at which workers would mark with timestamps for when crawling of that URL was started and finished. If a worker dies, another worker will pick up the work by noticing the work wasn't completed within a timeout period.
- Given a worker could crawl a few hundred pages a second, it would make sense for workers to grab a large number of URLs at a time for processing for efficiency. I'm not sure of an easy way to limit the number of crawls made to a single host per second though.
- When workers enqueue links, the database query to do so would avoid enqueuing links already seen.

I've read a few articles about how you shouldn't (and should!) use PostgreSQL as a queue...my thoughts here for using the database for a queue is that it's more cost efficient (AWS SQS sounds costly at $0.50 per million requests), the workers need to write page metadata to the database anyway so it needs to be able to cope with the throughput for that already and (maybe MQ systems can do this) it lets me code complex queuing logic.

Does the above sound like it would work? I've read a few articles on crawlers but most aren't explicit about how the workers communicate and where the URL frontier is stored so that it is resilient to failures.

Comment: If you use PostgreSQL 9.5 with `SKIP LOCKED` support this will be OK. If you need an older version use an external task/message queue engine on top of the DB.

Comment: @CraigRinger AWS only supports 9.4. Why would not having SKIP LOCKED be so bad and what do other distributed crawlers use?

Comment: Without `SKIP LOCKED` you can get decent queuing behaviour with proper use of advisory locks, so it's not that bad. It's just much harder to get right, especially for the failure cases. AFAIK crawlers etc use task or message queues layered on top of the DB for that reason. Most attempts to do it with regular transactional locking will be buggy, and either not recover from failed workers, risk handing out jobs to be processed more than once, or provide false concurrency where they *seem* to be parallel, but only one worker is actually doing anything at any given time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your frontier I think you should look at [frontera](https://github.com/scrapinghub/frontera) or [distributed-frontera](https://github.com/scrapinghub/distributed-frontera) from [scrapinghub](https://github.com/scrapinghub)

Frontera give you a lot up front like storage and scoring for your frontier links. Also, it is written in Python, which makes it easy to reason about and edit going forward.

Last point -- the documentation is fantastic and gave me a head-start in reasoning about how web crawlers can scale.

Using frontera with scrapyd and a custom dashboard has been a real treat. Currently deployed on Digital Ocean, but we could easily deploy to EC2 and AWS with frontera-distributed and EMR (HBASE).

Your proposal seems like it should work.